# Flakey TouchPad Not Fixed by Kernel Upgrade, 20.04

Tags: kernel, 20.04, touchpad

I'm a newbie to this site, but not new to Linux or Ubuntu. I have an ALPS PS/2 DualPoint TouchPad that's been acting flaky for several weeks. I also have the ALPS PS/2 DualPoint Stick, which works fine.

Since I have two almost identical computers and and both started the problem at about the same time, I knew it probably was a software problem. To be sure, I went to the bios before booting, and the touchpad worked fine. I tried two fixes suggested in other recent posts on the subject, reverting to 5.4.0-42 and blacklisting intel_vbtn, and neither worked. There are lots of recent posts with the problem here, and very few answers. Maybe someone can consolidate these.

Two things solved the problem for a few minutes. On one computer, I changed the keyboard (touchpad not part of keyboard) to a backlit one, not expecting that to do anything for the touchpad. To my surprise, the touchpad then worked fine for a few minutes. Then the problem came back. Yesterday, a kernel update came out, 5.4.0.51. When I installed it and rebooted, the touchpad worked fine and I thought the problem was solved. Then, after a few minutes the problem returned.

It's possible there's a kernel update coming down the pike that will fix this, and, if that's the case, I can be patient. It's also possible I got the kernel update that was supposed to fix it. If that's the case, kernel people need to know it's not fully fixed.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Update: Kernel 5.4.0.52 update. Same, solved the problem for a few minutes, then back to where it was.